# jQuery draggable after drop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I tried to figure out how to make dropped element again draggable to have possibility to drag it back. I have 2 divs with class .cell and I want to be able to drag and drop from both .cell to another

```
$('.users main .col.details form .row.stations .table .cell ul li').draggable({
    zIndex: 100,
    revert: true,
    opacity: 0.35,
    appendTo: "body",
    refreshPositions: true
});

$('.users main .col.details form .row.stations .table .cell').droppable({
    hoverClass: "drop-hover",
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        var classes = ui.draggable.attr('class');
        $("<li></li>").text( ui.draggable.text()).addClass(classes).appendTo($(this).find('ul'));
        ui.draggable.remove();
    }
});
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Did my answer below help? If not, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to re-create the `draggable` object when it's dropped in the `droppable` section. If you simply `append` the draggable `li`, it will maintain its "draggability":

```
$('.users main .col.details form .row.stations .table .cell').droppable({
  hoverClass: "drop-hover",
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    $(this).find('ul').append(ui.draggable);
  }
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/g41m9x8x/)**